# In Amsterdam, what kind of public workspaces are open on the last week of the year?

Tags: netherlands, holidays, amsterdam

I'm from a non-Christian non-European country, and I don't exactly have a good idea of what would be closed and what would be open on the last week of the year here in the Netherlands (and Amsterdam particularly): My workplace is closed, with everyone on vacation for the entire week.

Now, I would like to possibly go somewhere where I could sit down, use a computer, have a desk to write on etc. I was thinking of something like a public library, or perhaps some university building with these kinds of stations. Would these kinds of places be open?

A less-desirable alternative would be some cafe, but those are usually not so well-lit on the inside. But perhaps there are other kinds of publicly-accessible spaces that could do, and are open?